# Can I have an Encrypted Partition in a 2 Partitions USB Stick?

Tags: mac, disk-utility, encryption, disk-format

I have a new 16Gb USB key and want to take advantage of Disk Utilities feature to encrypt it, however I do need to move data from Mac to Windows from time to time.

Is is it possible to have one FAT partition and one Mac OS Extended Encrypted Partition on a 16Gb drive?
I've tried a number of times but cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found this thread hidden away in the Apple communities and it provided the solution. I was trying to do it through the Finder, I went back and tried it again using Disk Utility and it worked. Strange...

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3218292?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. It's pretty straight forward, to do so just:

1. Go to **Applications / Utilities / Disk Utilities**.
2. Select the USB device and click *Partitions*.
3. Choose the number of partitions you want and resize them as needed.
4. Choose the format of each partition and click *Apply.
5. Once mounted on the Finder, <kbd>Control</kbd>+Click the *Mac OS Extended* partition and choose **Encrypt**.
6. You'll be prompted  to choose a password. Enter it and click *Encrypt Disk*.
7. **Wait**. Unfortunately, there is no progress bar, so you won't know exactly how long will it take. I just did it with a **4 GB** USB drive and it took from **5** to **10 minutes**.

And it is done.

Comment: Hey, I had already tried that before asking and it failed. "The given file system is not supported on Core Storage". I also made sure my my partition scheme is GUID.

Comment: You can monitor the progress by calling "diskutil cs list" on the command line: Conversion Progress:   0%